# Gmail New Threading Policy requires workaround - how to fix?

Tags: vbscript, vb6, gmail, google-workspace, cdo.message

Per this announcement - https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/03/threading-changes-in-gmail-conversation-view.html -- an email with the exact same from/to and subject will no longer thread in Gmail if the emails are system generated unless we somehow reference the original message information in the subsequent system generated emails.

Does anyone have ideas for how we would do this in CDO mail using ASP / VBScript? Am guessing we would have to call a Google API to get the message ID after it created the message as well.

Google was not able to provide any help over and above the language used in this blog article which was as below:

> **Additional details**
>
> If you are managing a system that sends email notifications to users
>   and want your emails to be threaded in Gmail conversation view, then
>   you have to ensure that your notifications:
>
> 1) Have the same subject
>
> 2) Have reference headers that reference IDs seen earlier in the
>   thread, or have references headers that consistently refer to the same
>   message ID

Ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're looking for any sort of Google API, this sounds to be the standard "References" and "In-Reply-To" headers that any email reply should have. Refer to [section 3.6.4 "Identification Fields"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.4) in RFC 5322. To create this you'd need to read the Message-ID header of the email being replied to and use it in the References header.

Just read the Message-ID of the email you're replying to like any other header:

```
Dim OriginalMessageId as String
OriginalMessageId = originalEmail.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:message-id")
```

And use it to create the References headers in your new email:

```
replyEmail.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:references") = OriginalMessageId
replyEmail.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:in-reply-to") = OriginalMessageId
```

If you need more of a pointer of how this would work, you might need to include more of the code of how you're reading a message and how you're replying to it.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for reading and your reply.  I wasn't totally clear.  ALL of our messages with a common subject and from address / to address are system generated notification emails using CDO.  Previously it threaded but now due to this new requirement it does not.

Comment: So, if you're not adding the References header in your replies, you need to do so. I'm not sure what you are unclear about.

Comment: Correct me if wrong, but it sounds like we will have to somehow database the Reference header that gets generated AFTER email #1 is sent. What I am unclear about is I am not sure how I read that message-id value in after sending a CDO message - I am sending using CDO via Gmail SMTP servers. Or are you suggesting I try to assign that message-id before sending? I have tried to research how to extract message-id but have not found anything clear. Your help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I think you need to be clearer on your workflow here... Are you trying to somehow get things threaded that *aren't* a reply that you're sending?

Comment: I think the answer is yes.  We are periodically adding notes about a topic from an external system and when we do that we are choosing the option to copy that note to an email that is not technically a "reply" but is related and we thus want it to thread.  Another example are SMS conversations that are being posted from an external system that we want to look like a conversation inside Gmail.  Previously they threaded, now they don't.   Does that help?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure how well it will work to try to trick Gmail into thinking things are replies when they really aren't, but if you set the Message-Id header in the initial email (per the RFC), and then put that same Id in the References header of subsequent emails, it might work the way you want.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame they changed things to where I have to now trick the system and that they didn't make it a configurable option to keep it the old way for our domain.  So it sounds like you are saying trying to create the Message-ID header value, I will look into that possibility.  Thank you.